# ¿Por qué se me pone el valor 0 cuando deberia ser 1?

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy haciendo el juego de la vida de John Conway con pygame. Estoy añadiendo las reglas pero en un caso donde debería tener la lista un valor de 1 lo tiene de 0. El código es el siguiente, donde creo una lista 5x5 rellena de 0, establezco los siguientes valores a 1 que deberían producir un patrón que se repite. Creo una nueva lista 5x5 vacía, la que voy modificando para crear la nueva generación y así no alterar la lista de la generación actual. En esta cambio de 0 a 1 o viceversa dependiendo del número de celdas vecinas que esten vivas (tengan un valor de 1). EL código es el siguiente:

```
arr = [[0 for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]

arr[2][1]=1
arr[2][2]=1
arr[2][3]=1

for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr[i])):
        if i>0 and i<(len(arr)-1) and j>0 and j<(len(arr[i])-1):
            alive = 0
            # Compruebo el estado de las 8 celdas vecinas
            if arr[i-1][j-1] == 1:
                alive+=1
            if arr[i-1][j] == 1:
                alive+=1
            if arr[i-1][j+1] == 1:
                alive+=1
            if arr[i][j-1] == 1:
                alive+=1
            if arr[i][j+1] == 1:
                alive+=1
            if arr[i+1][j-1] == 1:
                alive+=1
            if arr[i+1][j] == 1:
                alive+=1
            if arr[i+1][j+1] == 1:
                alive+=1
            # Reglas para las celdas vivas
            if arr[i][j] == 1:
                # Si la celda tiene menos de dos celdas vecinas vivas muere por despoblación.
                if alive < 2:
                    next_gen_arr[i][j] = 0
                # Si la celda tiene exactamente dos o tres celdas vecinas vivas pasan a la siguiente generación vivas.
                elif alive == 2 or alive == 3:
                    next_gen_arr[i][j]==1
                # Si la celda tiene más de 3 celdas vecinas vivas muere por sobrepoblación.
                else:
                    next_gen_arr[i][j] = 0
            # Regla para las celdas muertas.
            elif arr[i][j] == 0:
                # Si una celda muerta tiene exactamente 3 celdas vivas vecinas nace por reproducción.
                if alive == 3:
                    next_gen_arr[i][j] = 1
arr = next_gen_arr
```

Si imprimimos ambas listas nos debería dar lo siguiente:

Lista que introduzco (arr):
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

Resultado correcto:
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

Lista que obtengo (arr al final):
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

Comment: Esta linea deberia ser = y no ==:  elif alive == 2 or alive == 3:
                    next_gen_arr[i][j]==1

Comment: Vaya tontería, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si, es una de esas "tonterias" que nos han hecho perder mucho tiempo a todos alguna vez... Repasas el código cien veces y tu cerebro "eso esta bien bro..." XD. Por cierto, si quieres puedes prescindir de los if encadenados, simplemente suma las celdas: `alive = arr[i-1][j-1] + arr[i-1][j] + arr[i-1][j+1] + arr[i][j-1] + arr[i][j+1] + arr[i+1][j-1] + arr[i+1][j] + arr[i+1][j+1]`